# Why the proper time of photon is zero?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, photons, reference-frames, observers

I'm currently taking classes on General Relativity, and whilst working on Geodesis equation:

[image]

Find out that for mass particle q is equivalent to proper time but in case of photon the proper time of photon is zero.
Could you please explain why? (For note, surprisingly but i didn't have proper Special relativity lessons)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper time for a light particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/349802/)

Answer (score 0):

Because for a massless particle $ds^2=0$.

Comment: While this is correct, I don't think it will be terribly useful to the OP without more details.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert it should be useful for the OP as he is taking GR classes.

Comment: They also say that their special relativity background is weak, though.

Comment: I think this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/709601/281096 although given to other question would be more helpful.