# What is the real world interpretation of $E = mc^2$?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass-energy

Why I am asking this question:

- There appears to be a logical contradiction in the notion that gravity is "one thing"
- mass moves in gravity much differently than light (a massless particle)
- allowing light to be truly massless, light follows the space-time curve
- mass follows the space time curve + some additional direct mass-mass component

The geodesic path for massive objects:

$$\frac{d p^\mu}{d\lambda} + \Gamma^\mu_{\beta\sigma}p^\beta p^\sigma = 0$$

And the geodesic path for massless objects:

$$\frac{d p^0}{d\lambda} + \Gamma^0_{00}p^0p^0= 0$$

---

The point here is one of interpretation. If an entire component (the spatial component?) drops when mass is dropped (as in light), does this not indicate gravity is a composition of effects rather than any one effect in isolation?

I would understand a 1:many effect of a force-type on different objects, but not a many:many effect, which this whole gravity ball of math appears to be.

So rather than hang my logic up at the door, I am trying to explain this.

---

What is the current state-of-the-art **physical** interpretation of the equation $E = mc^2$?

Comment: "I am interpreting mass as a bundle of light, and somehow this bundle of gyroscopic light reacts more strongly to curvature induced by gravity, has inertia, and has other special properties." Unless this interpretation has any *testable, falsifiable consequences*, or is taken as a *definition* of one or more of the words contained in the statement, it is simply and plainly an unscientific interpretation.

Comment: The Einstein field equations state that the components of the metric ("the curvature of space-time") and it's derivatives, are given by the stress-energy tensor. The stress energy tensor contains contributions from both matter and light. Not sure what more there is to say?

Comment: see my answer here for  relativistic mass and invariant mass. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16233/

Comment: Please remember [the rules of this forum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour): you can ask for explanations about phenomena or accepted theories, but not about non-mainstream physics or personal theories. Also, questions with too many possible answers are also discouraged.

Comment: The comment section isn't the right place for this (or the thread will be sent to a separate chat). If you trim your initial question into a scientific enquiry, then actual answers will be possible.

Comment: Please do not edit a question to ask a completely different question, but *[ask a new question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead*. You have already received (and accepted) an answer to the previous version of your question, and the edit makes that answer completely incomprehensible.

Comment: I have rolled back your question. As @ACuriousMind said, editing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers is not allowed. Please ask a new question instead, or if you are unable to then read the guidance [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/380389). Please do not rollback the edit again, or this post is likely to be locked.

Comment: Somewhat confusing that the mod is named Chris and the OP is also named Chris...

Comment: @hft Pretty funny.

Comment: @Chris  I really don't care that much.  Can't complement the user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of your question differs somewhat from the title. I'll tackle the title first: the "real world" interpretation of the equation is given by the title of Einstein's original paper, "Does the inertia of a body depend on its energy content?", to which he answered "yes" and gave the formula $m = \frac{E}{c^2}$, where $m$ is the inertia contributed by the energy. That is, as you add energy to a body it gains inertia (and hence is harder to push).

It was soon realized that this equation also implied that the "rest mass" (or rest inertia) of a body also contains energy, and the equation is today usually written to emphasize this as $E = mc^2$.

In any case the $m$ here is "inertial mass", that is the same $m$ as in $F = ma$, and *not* gravitational mass.

Gravity is a whole different story, and we now know that gravity is *not* due (only) to mass or energy, but is due to something called the stress-energy tensor. This has 10 independent components, one of which corresponds to energy, 3 to momentum, and 6 to stress and pressure. For massive bodies moving at slow speed the energy (in fact the rest mass) dominates, and Newton's law of gravity comes out as a good approximation, but for relativistic bodies such as light then yes, there are other components which must be taken into account.

EDIT: I should clarify that those other components only matter when light is considered as a *source* of gravity. As far as the effects of gravity *on* light are concerned, the extra deflection is due to the bending of space. That is, in a geometric interpretation of Newton's gravity, only time is bent. But in general relativity both space and time are bent, so the deflection is twice as great. The space deflection applies to everything equally, not just light... but for "slow" moving bodies like planets it's really hard to notice the spatial deflection because the temporal deflection dominates so much. It's only when something is moving through space almost as fast as it moves through time that we notice the spatial part of gravity.

Comment: No, not in general relativity, which models gravity as spacetime curvature. Trying to make a quantum mechanical theory of gravity (which would be conceptually more like a traditional force) is an active research area. But so far all the data from experiments are in agreement with relativity. Physicists would really like to find some case where GR doesn't work, as it might give a clue as to how quantum gravity might work.

Comment: Relativity is definitely falsifiable -- it produces specific predictions for black holes, time dilation, gravitational waves, planetary orbits, and so on, and many of those things were predicted by GR before being discovered. The "problem" (such as it is) is that it hasn't been falsified yet: it's passed all tests so far, and there have been a lot of them. Physicists would like to have some clues as to how quantum mechanics interacts with gravity, but so far there are no hints of anything beyond GR.

Comment: @Chris whether one of the most important, well-tested, precise physical theories of all time has a satisfying interpretation is subjective, don't you agree? It is certainly satisfying to the professors who teach SR and GR at my university. Is it *intuitive*? Maybe not, but why would it be? Humans have very little personal experience with relativistic effects in daily life, so how would we build intuition about it without studying it thoroughly?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I disagree.  The current model is always the most successful.  And this is a model, not a theory.  Without a physical interpretation, there can be no "now what", reason why, or decomposition into components.  We have a parameterized monolith, and that is that.  Anyways, suspect open source relativity is insufficient for military purposes (icbm dead reckoning and submarine guidance), so there is that.

Comment: 1) "I disagree" With what? 2) "And this is a model, not a theory". All physical theories are based on models of (aspects of) the universe. According to the first sentence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), "**General relativity**, (is) also known as the **general theory of relativity** (...)" so maybe we are operating with different defintions of what a theory is.

Comment: 3) Maybe I was not expressing myself clearly enough, but I am not of the opinion that "the tensor" does not *have* a physical explanation; of course it does! As stated in Eric's answer, the components of the tensor correspond to energy, mass, stress and pressure. Likewise, the equation $E=mc^2$ also has a physical interpretation. What I *am* trying to convey is that we (humans) cannot reasonably expect that the laws that govern how Nature works (if such laws exist) are in any way "satisfying" or "simple" or "intuitive" or any other adjectives.

Comment: And as you are surely aware, the GPS system and the satellites that ensures that the system operates as intended are feats of engineering that **depend on GR to function properly**. This is but one example of the research "paying off".

Comment: I understand. Let me ask this then: What really are "electric charge", "electric field", "magnetic field", "electromagnetic field energy density"? Are you saying that you have answers to these questions that are more satisfying than the anwers to "what is mass" and "what is energy"? If so, maybe I will understand better what you are after by reading those answers.

Comment: Your comments about ICBMs and household electronics are interesting, and I certainly agree that Einstein's field equations cannot tell you how the wifi antenna works **in practice**; that is not what the equations are for, either. But are you sure that the reason GR cannot be used to guide your IBCMs is due to a *fundamental* missing element of the theory?? Isn't it just because the stress-energy tensor relevant for the missile's motion is **ridiculously complicated in practice**?

Answer (score 2):

The path of any particle, irrespective of mass, is given by the geodesic equation:

$$\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\lambda^2}+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\beta}{d\lambda}=0$$

where $\lambda$ is a suitable affine parameter. One must be careful though, because although for massive particles we often choose the affine parameter to be proper-time $\tau$, this is ill-defined for a massless particle because in that case $d\tau=0$ everywhere along the path.

The four-momentum of a massive particle is given by $m v^\mu$, where $m$ is a Lorentz-scalar (i.e. constant) and $v^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ is the four-velocity. For a massive particle, $v^\mu v_\mu = -1$ (assuming the mostly plus metric convention), and therefore $p^\mu p_\mu=-m^2$. Multiplying this entire equation by $m^2$ thus gives, for a massive particle,

$$m\frac{dp^\mu}{d\lambda}+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}p^\alpha p ^\beta=0$$

The four momentum of a massless particle is does not have a simple relation with its four-velocity, because the four-velocity is ill-defined for a massless particle! (because $d\tau=0$ everywhere along its path) Instead, the regular velocity of a massless particle is given by

$$V^\mu\equiv \frac{dx^\mu}{dt}=(1,\hat n)$$

where $n^2=1$. Then the four-momentum is given by $p V^\mu=E \frac{dx^\mu}{dt}$.

The physical interpretation of $E=mc^2$, which by the way I think you mean $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$, is simply the definition $p^\mu p_\mu = -m^2$ written explicitly, where $p^\mu=\left(\frac{E}{c^2},\frac{\vec p}{c}\right)$. Each variable $E$, $\vec p$, and $m$ are physical measurable quantities for any particle. The interesting thing is that they are all related by the relation $p^\mu p_\mu = -m^2$ where $p^\mu$ is defined as given previously.